# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'question' on Python

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror, python-class

I met with the following issue AttributeError, but I have checked the syntax and indentation, and found no mistakes. Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong?

```
class Question():
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

question_prompts = [
    "What color are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n",
    "What color are bananas?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magenta\n(c) Yellow\n",
    "What color are strawberries?\n(a) Yellow\n(b) Red\n(c) Blue\n",
]

tasks = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
]

def run_test(tasks):
    score = 0
    for items in tasks:
        answer = input(tasks.question)
        if answer == tasks.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(question_prompts)) + " correct")

run_test(tasks)
```

Exception:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'question'
```

Comment: `tasks` is a list. `items` is an instance of `Question`. So, `answer = input(items.question)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the entire list of Questions and trying to index the `.question` attribute so it looks at the list container instead of the individual object, this would be fixed by :-

```
answer = input(items.question)
```

As items is the variable containing the Question object on each pass of the loop. You'll have to change the answer check accordingly as well